# Добавление Строки В Таблицу Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть таблица, выведенная на форму, туда можно вписать новые данные в ячейки, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы данные сохранялись и в приложении, и в связанной базе по нажатию на кнопку.

Насколько я понимаю, в принципе все управление содержимым таблицы делается через `ObservableCollection<Т>`, однако все встреченные мной примеры применения выглядели примерно  так:

```
    ObservableCollection<Client> coll = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
    coll.Add(new Client() { 
       Name = "Frank Grimmes", EMail = "mail@mail.mail" 
    });
```

то есть на каждую таблицу мы создаем класс, и потом его полям через коллекцию передаем данные, которые пишутся внутри кода, руками. А как сделать, чтобы в коллекцию добавлялось то, что содержится в новой заполненной ячейке?

Comment: Вас интересует добавление новой строки в коллекцию `coll`?